# Collapse sections onclick

Tags: html, css

I have two sections on my page, and I want to collapse/expand them together when the user clicks on any of them. What happens is that each section is collapse/expand alone. How can this be solved?

```css
.collapse-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.collapse-input:checked~p {
  height: auto;
}

.collapse {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.collapse-input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.collapse-content {
  transition: .2s ease-in;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div className="collapse-container">
  <section className="collapse">
    <input className="collapse-input" type="checkbox" />
    <p className="collapse-title">First Section</p>
    <p className="collapse-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section className="collapse">
    <input className="collapse-input" type="checkbox" />
    <p className="collapse-title">Second Section</p>
    <p className="collapse-content">
      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: this is really **unclear**, what do you expect ?  `collapse/expand together`or  `collapse/expand alone`  ?

Comment: @MisterJojo i expect to be collapse/expand together

Comment: you need javascript codding for that.

Comment: PS, your CSS does not produce any collapse on anything

Comment: Are you looking for a solution without JavaScript?

Comment: you can also consider using https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp but you need javascript for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Op needs all `<label>`s to be able to control all content. See **Alternate** and **Example B**.

If you are using invisible checkboxes as switches, then you should add a `<label>` and associate each one to a checkbox by the `for` attribute value matching the `id` attribute of the checkbox (see **Figure I**). Once an association is established between an `<input>` and a `<label>` any click on the `<label>` automatically confers to it's associated `<input>`.

The collapsible content must proceed the `<input>` -- other tags can be between them as long as it is the same for all `<input>`/`<label>` pairs. **Figure II**  is the CSS for the content in it's hidden state, if you want the content to be visible initially, then add the `checked` attribute to the `<input>`.

**Figure I**

```html
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" style="display: none">
<label for="chk1"><!-- [for = "ID of checkbox"] -->
  This is the part of the collapsible that is constantly
  visible and clickable
</label>  
<p>This is the collapsible content</p>
```

**Figure II**

```css
p {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.65s ease-in-out;
}
```

Next, you'll need a CSS ruleset involving the `<input>` being checked and the position of the content relative to the `<input>`. The CSS pseudo-class `:checked` indicates that the style will be active only when a checkbox/radio button is checked. The [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator): `+` indicates the element that is directly following the previous element (see **Figure III**)

**Figure III**

```css
input:checked + label + p {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

### Example A

```css
.switch {
  display: none;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title:hover {
  color: red;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease;
}

.switch:checked+.title+.content {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <input id="col1" class="switch" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="col1" class="title">First Section</label>
    <p class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input id="col2" class="switch" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="col2" class="title">Second Section</label>
    <p class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

### Alternate

Simply remove all but one `<input>`. Move that single `<input>` before the first `<section>`. Next, change the `for` attribute of each `<label>` as the `id` of that single `<input>`. See **Figure IV** for CSS. The `~` is a [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

**Figure IV**

```css
/* Change this */
.switch:checked+.title+.content {
  max-height: 300px;
}
/* to this */
.switch:checked~section .content {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

### Example B

```css
.switch {
  display: none;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title:hover {
  color: red;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease;
}

.switch:checked~section .content {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input id="col" class="switch" type="checkbox" />
  <section>
    <label for="col" class="title">First Section</label>
    <p class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label for="col" class="title">Second Section</label>
    <p class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: i need the 2 sections to be collapsed or expanded together when any of the 2 labels are clicked

Answer (score 0):

Although you've set the height to 0, the text is still being shown because of overflow. So initially, add `overflow: hidden` to the text to hide it. Then add `overflow: auto` to the *checked* text to show it again.

```css
.collapse-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
.collapse {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse-input {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse-content {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;   /*change here*/
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}
.collapse-input:checked~p{
    height: 20px;       /*use specific height instead of auto for transition*/
    overflow: auto;     /*change here*/
}
```

```html
<div className="collapse-container">
  <section class="collapse">
    <input class="collapse-input" type="checkbox" />
    <p class="collapse-title">First Section</p>
    <p class="collapse-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="collapse">
    <input class="collapse-input" type="checkbox" />
    <p class="collapse-title">Second Section</p>
    <p class="collapse-content">
      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: i need the 2 sections to be collapsed or expanded together when any of the 2 labels are clicked